# Heroku's Heroku-Config plugin gets lodash/array error when running or installing

Tags: heroku, lodash, heroku-toolbelt

I had previously installed the Heroku Toolbelt heroku-config plugin and had been using it to push and pull the app's config vars without any problems but now its getting a lodash/array error:

```
Can't find module 'lodash/array'
```

This occurs when trying to run the plugin as in:

```
heroku config:push -f <env file name> -o -a <app name>
```

I removed and reinstalled the latest Node 
Removed and reinstalled Heroku Toolbelt.
Then,
When installing the heroku-config plugin I now get the very same error when running:

```
heroku plugin:install heroku-config
```

on Mac OS X - El Capitan 10.11.6

[image]

UPDATE:
I have removed and reinstalled the Heroku Toolbelt CLI and removed the heroku-config plugin and then reinstalled the Heroku Toolbelt CLI then when trying to install the heroku-config plugin I get the same error of Cannot find module 'loash/array'.

I have concluded that this error is likely not a Heroku Toolbelt or a Node error but a heroku-config plugin error as the Heroku Toolbeld CLI can run other commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved

After removing and reinstalling the Heroku Toolbelt CLI and still having the problem, then making sure the paths were correct and restarting the terminal window etc....still the problem.

Rebooted Mac and problem solved....arrggghhhh....don't know where the problem originated and don't know if any of the removal / reinstall had any bearing on it.

After I removed and reinstalled the Heroku Toolbelt CLI it couldn't even reinstall the "config" plugin that was the origin problem - kept having the same "lodash/array" problem.